# Import 3D model Threejs

Tags: three.js

i tried to import a 3D model but I'm not sure if i m doing in right way.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load('./CesiumMilkTruck.gltf', 
        function (gltf) {

            scene.add(gltf.scene);
            gltf.animations; 
            gltf.scene;
            gltf.scenes; 
            gltf.cameras; 
            gltf.asset;


        },

        function (xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },

        function (error) {
            console.log( 'An error happened = ', error );
        }
    );
```

my html is

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

I download the model on this page :

[link](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/CesiumMilkTruck/glTF)

in particular i download the three files:

CesiumMilkTruck.gltf
CesiumMilkTruck.png

CesiumMilkTruck0.bin

I had this errors:

```
An error happened =  SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at 
line 7 column 1 of the JSON data" parse 

file:///C:/Users/an/Desktop/master/js/GLTFLoader.js:157
load file:///C:/Users/an/Desktop/master/js/GLTFLoader.js:75
load file:///C:/Users/an/Desktop/master/js/three.min.js:715
```

What I m wrong?

Sorry for my question, but is my first time with Threejs.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have an issue with the GLTF model, perhaps corrupted?. The error message would lead me to believe that the formatting of the GLTF file is incorrect (it's all numerical).

Here is a code excerpt from my flight simulator I'm building with Threejs and Konva.js: https://github.com/mpaccione/everest_flight_sim

In the code below I load in a helicopter model, turn it wireframe, and add it to a group which contains the first person camera so it seems you are flying a helicopter.

I'm using commonJS modules with browserfy for this project.

```
const GLTFLoader = require('three-gltf-loader'),
      miniModelLoader = new GLTFLoader();
```

```
// Load Helicopter Model
miniModelLoader.load( './src/models/helicopter/scene.gltf', function(gltf){
    miniModel = gltf.scene;
    miniModel.name = "miniHeli"
    miniModel.rotation.y = -90 * Math.PI / 180; // Radians
    miniModel.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    let miniModelMesh = miniModel.children[0].children[0].children[0],
        miniModelMeshArr = [ miniModelMesh.children[0], miniModelMesh.children[1], miniModelMesh.children[2] ];

    for (var i = miniModelMeshArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        miniModelMeshArr[i].material.wireframe = true;
    }

    miniHeliGroup.add( miniModel );
} )
```

Comment: const GLTFLoader = require('three-gltf-loader'),
      miniModelLoader = new GLTFLoader();  go to the same js file?

Comment: This is the NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-gltf-loader

Comment: The first variable pulls in the code from the npm package I installed. The second variable creates an instantiation of said code. Basically it creates a loader from the module.